# Given a table containing a list of exams taken, write a SQL query to add a column for attempt number

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Scenario:
I have a table that contains a log of exams taken. When a person first takes an exam, it is considered valid for a year. Every year their exam expires and the person has to come back and retake the exam (they are allowed to re-take it within 6 months of their expiration date).

I want to write a query to add a column for "AttemptNumber". Each time a person takes a specific exam their attempt number should increase (the earliest DateCompleted should be the first attempt number). But the attempt number should reset if there is more than a 6 month gap between attempts, because this would be considered the following year's renewal attempt.

| ExamAttemptID (primary key) | PersonID | ExamID | DateCompleted | Passed | AttemptNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Exam101 | 7/1/2023 | False | 1 |
| 2 | A | Exam101 | 7/3/2023 | False | 2 |
| 3 | A | Exam101 | 7/4/2023 | True | 3 |
| 4 | B | Exam101 | 12/30/2023 | False | 1 |
| 5 | B | Exam101 | 1/3/2024 | True | 2 |
| 6 | A | Exam101 | 7/6/2024 | False | 1 |
| 7 | A | Exam101 | 7/7/2024 | True | 2 |
| 8 | A | Exam551 | 7/8/2024 | True | 1 |

I'm working in pyspark SQL.

I'm thinking something along the lines of below, but can't figure out the 6 month reset...

```
SELECT 
  ExamAttemptID, 
  PersonID, 
  ExamID, 
  DateCompleted, 
  Passed,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, ExamID ORDER BY DateCompleted ASC RANGE ??) 
FROM ExamLog
```

Comment: IIUC pyspark  is not SQL Server

Comment: Provide your sample data as DDL+DML and you make it much easier for people to assist... I mean who wants to manually type out your sample data in order to build a query.

Comment: You're describing a *gaps & islands* solution; Search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Stu for giving a name to the problem! searching for sql gaps & islands  led me right to a solution!

Here is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT 
 ExamAttemptID, 
 PersonID, 
 ExamID, 
 DateCompleted, 
 Passed,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IslandId ORDER BY DateCompleted) AS AttemptNumber
FROM 
(   
  SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN DateCompleted BETWEEN X.PreviousDateCompleted AND DATEADD(MONTH, 6, X.PreviousDateCompleted) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IslandStartInd,
    SUM (CASE WHEN DateCompleted BETWEEN X.PreviousDateCompleted AND DATEADD(MONTH, 6, X.PreviousDateCompleted) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY X.RN) AS IslandId
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY PersonID, ExamID, DateCompleted ) AS RN,
      MAX(DateCompleted) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, ExamID ORDER BY DateCompleted ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PreviousDateCompleted,
        *
    FROM ExamLog
  ) X
) Y
order by IslandId
```

This medium article led me in the right direction:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sql-classic-problem-identifying-gaps-and-islands-across-overlapping-date-ranges-5681b5fcdb8